# Get the Width of Div and LIMIT the mySQL query according to no of elements?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I needed to display number of images in

```
<li><img class='1'><img class='1'><img class='1'></li>
<li><img class='1'><img class='1'><img class='1'></li>
```

but as my div is auto increasing according to screen width. I needed to calculate number of images to display according to the width of div , suppose width is 1200px and each image will be of 150px . so the number of image to display are 8 .

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var screen_width = document.getElementById('div_1').offsetWidth();
var no_of_images =Math.round(screen_width/100);
</script>
```

I am getting the images from mysql database, using LIMIT query .. I want to LIMIT it to no of images i got using var no_of_images. But as their is no direct rule of integrating javascript variable into mysql query. i want to pass it to PHP variable and then use it in Mysql. But unfortunately i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `document.ready` event handler to make sure the DOM is ready to be manipulated and then make an AJAX request to your server-side script that could output the HTML for the correct number of images to place in the container:

```
//wait for the `document.ready` event to fire
$(function () {

    //cache the container element since it will be used later more than once
    //also get the width of the container and figure out how many 150px wide images can fit without being clipped
    //note that this does not take into consideration any padding/margin/border for the images
    var $container   = $('#div_1'),
        screen_width = $container.width(),
        no_of_images = Math.floor(screen_width / 150);

    //create an AJAX call to your server-side script to get the image HTML
    $.ajax({
        url  : '<URL>',
        type : 'get',//or 'post'
        data : { 'no_of_images' : no_of_images },//jQuery will handle data encoding if you pass it an object
        success : function (serverResponse) {

            //now the AJAX request has returned successfully so this fades the container out, replaces it's HTML with the server response and then fades back in
            $container.fadeOut(500, function () {
                $container.html(serverResponse).fadeIn(500);
            });
        },

        //if an error occurs with the AJAX call this is how you handle it, you may just try to re-send the AJAX call
        error   : function () {
            alert('an error occured');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it as a get param when loading the page. e.g. when creating the link to load the next page just add it as param. on initial page load you get all the images bu display only the ones you need for the available resolution

Comment: I know about that but really that is not what i need. Is there any way to get offset width of a div in PHP. Then i can solve my problem

Comment: no you can't access that from PHP. PHP runs on the server, javascript on the client side. the only way to pass something back is by reloading the page or making an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var screen_width = document.getElementById('div_1').offsetWidth();
    var no_of_images =Math.round(width/100);

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "script.php",
        data: "no_of_images="+no_of_images,
        success: function(){
            // do something
        }
    });
</script>
```

You have to use jQuery to get my code working, cause i used the jQuery method $.ajax().